# Intuitive statement of tangent space theorems

Tags: differential-geometry

There are four theorems concerning about tagent spaces:

> Let $M\subset\mathbb R^k$ be a smooth m dimensional manifold and fix a point $p\in M$. Then the following holds.
>
> (i)Let $U_0\subset M$ be an M open set with $p\in U_0$ and $\phi_0\to \Omega_0$ be a diffeomorphism onto an open subset $\Omega_0\subset \mathbb R^m.$ Let $x_0:=\phi_0(p)$ and let $\psi:={\phi_0}^{-1}:\Omega_0\to U_0$ be the inverse map. Then $$T_pM=im(d\psi_0(x_0):{\mathbb R}^m\to {\mathbb R}^k).$$
>
> (ii) Let $U,\Omega\subset \mathbb R^k$ be open sets and $\phi:U\to\Omega$ be a diffeomorphism such that $p\in U$ and $\phi(U\bigcap M)=\Omega\bigcap({\mathbb R^m\times\{0\}})$. Then $$T_pM=d\phi(p)^{-1}({\mathbb R^m\times\{0\}}).$$
>
> (iii)Let $U\subset \mathbb R^k$ be an open neighborhood of $p$ and $f:U\to{\mathbb R}^{k-m}$ be a smooth map such that $0$ is a regular value of f and $U\bigcap M=f^{-1}(0).$ Then $$T_pM=\ker df(p).$$
>
> (iv)$T_pM$ is an m dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb R^k$.

But the problem is that they all seem to abstract to me. What is the informal statement of these that is more intuitive, and easy to interpret?

Comment: Maybe try considering $m=2,k=3$ for geometric intuition.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=tangent+plane&biw=1778&bih=1028&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=egaaVOqQEIOvogSjw4GwBw&sqi=2&pjf=1&ved=0CFIQsAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an intuitive picture, imagine your manifold is embedded in some Euclidean space.

In an $m$ dimensional manifold $M$, you want the tangent space at $p \in M$ to be an $m$ dimensional plane just touching $p$ which is a local approximation to $M$. Note that the derivative of a map is the linear map defined to give you a close approximation to the local curvature near $p$. Therefore, it should make sense that the image of $d\psi_0$, shifted by $p$ (which by definition gives you a vector space, and then an affine space after the shift), should be this close approximation; it can also be proven that with this definition, the dimensions are the same. Note that the domain of $d\psi_0$ is just $\mathbb{R}^m$, reflecting the fact that you parametrize the manifold from flat space. This treats at least (i) and (iv).

For (iii), you might make a loose analogy with projecting $M$ down onto lower dimensional space, but I'm not sure if this is easily visualized.

The $\phi(U \cap M) = \Omega \cap (\mathbb{R}^m \times \{0\})$ condition shows that diffeomorphism $\phi$ in (ii) maps $M$ locally onto the $m$-dimensional plane (viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$), which effectively parametrizes it, so it's very similar to (i) in terms of visualization; note that you can show that $d\psi_0$ is an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $T_pM$, which means that the equation for $T_pM$ in (i) and (ii) are basically the same thing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you define a tangent vector and a tangent space?

Comment: I'm starting here with the Guillemin and Pollack definition, which is that the tangent space at $x$ is the image of the derivative of a local parametrization at $x$.